# address of dynamic array

Tags: c++

I have this code which returns the address of a dynamic array by pointer .. but how can I return the address of a dynamic array by reference ? thank you..

```
int* e(int a[][2],int rows)
{
    int *p;

    p=new int[2];

    int max,min;

    max=min=a[0][0];

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            if(min>a[i][j])
                min=a[i][j];
            else if(max<a[i][j])
                max=a[i][j];
            else;
        }
    }

    p[0]=min;
    p[1]=max;
    delete []p;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>` instead of `new int[]` and suddenly all of your problems are solved.

Comment: "but how can I return the address of a dynamic array by reference" Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @GManNickG I have this homework you know :)

Comment: You cannot return `p` by reference as using the returned pointer would be UB so if your teacher wants you to do that, he's a bad teacher (you'd need to dynamically allocate a pointer to the array and return that by reference).

Comment: Also just use `std::vector` and return that by value, really. See http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/.

Answer (score 3):

"Return(ing) the address of a dynamic array by reference" in this case would come down to returning `p` by reference, but `p` is a local variable, so the memory would get freed when the function exits, so that won't work.

**If you really want to, this should work:** (but I **strongly** doubt that this is what you're supposed to do, and would probably lead to a memory leak)

```
int* &e(int a[][2],int rows)
{
  int **p = new int*;
  *p = new int[2];
  ...
  return *p;
}
```

**Note that this doesn't make sense:**

```
delete []p;
return p;
```

You're freeing the memory, then returning a pointer to it.

Just remove the delete and everything should be fine (or at least closer to fine).